# Updating Variables From a Dictionary In a For Loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, variable-assignment

in this piece of code I want to update some varaiables(`x` and `y` in this case) by looping through a dictionary that has the variables hashed to the new values I want to assign them to. But when I try using a `for` loop for looping through and assigning the variables, I only end up updating the temporary loop `var` and not the actual keys/variables. Please help me update these variables by somehow looping through the dictionary.

```
x = 5
y = 10

dict1 = {x : 5,
         y : 10
}

for var in dict1:
  var -= dict1[var]
  

print(x,y)
print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misconceptions on how dictionaries and variables work. By writing

```
dict1 = {x: 5}
```

You're writing the equivalent of

```
dict1 = {5: 5}
```

Because you're using the ***value*** x and not the ***variable name*** x.

What you want to do might be achieved by using [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals), but I advise against it - there is almost always a simpler, less "dark-magic" solution. Nevertheless, an example:

```
x, y = 5, 10
dict1 = {
    "x" : 5,
    "y" : 10
}

for var in dict1:
    locals()[var] -= dict1[var]

print(x,y)
print(dict1)
```

Comment: But what does the locals() function do? Also, how are you updating the variables just by making a string instead of the variable name?

Comment: I linked the python documentation about `locals()`, so you can read about it there. I repeat my suggestion not to use this as a real-world solution to a real-world problem - there is probably a better, different way to do it without updating "lists of variables"

Comment: Wait a minute, I changed the locals() to globals(), but the program is still working. So, what’s the difference?

Comment: Different scopes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules